# Oracle UTL_HTTP thorws ORA-28860 and ORA-24263

Tags: ssl, plsql, oracle

I have installed Oracle 12C.

I have imported 5 SSL certificates to the Wallet, their CA names:

- GTS Root R1
- GTS CA 1C3
- GTS CA 1P5
- E1
- ISRG Root X2

I'm aware that Oracle 12C only need root and intermediate certificate(s), not any site certificate. Thus I imported only root and intermediate certificates.

My code for testing UTL_HTTP connection:

```
DECLARE
    lo_req  UTL_HTTP.req;
    lo_resp UTL_HTTP.resp;
BEGIN
    UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET('<path-to-wallet>', '<password>');
    lo_req := UTL_HTTP.begin_request('<url>');
    lo_resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response(lo_req);
    dbms_output.put_line('Status code is ' || lo_resp.status_code);
    UTL_HTTP.end_response(lo_resp);
END;
/
```

Following URLs could be accessed without issues:

- https://maps.googleapis.com
- https://maps.google.com

Following URLs throw "ORA-24263: Certificate of the remote server does not match the target address.":

- https://googleapis.com
- https://google.com

Following URLs throw "ORA-28860: Fatal SSL error":

- https://wtfismyip.com
- https://stackoverflow.com

How to configure Oracle to be able access URLs like "https://google.com" or "https://stackoverflow.com"?